# Angular.js: Display an ng-repeat item in a modal/dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-dialog

I have looked at angular-ui bootstrap and ng-dialog and they appear overkill for what I need viz:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">      
  <div class="dialog-content">
    <h5 ng-click="dialog_open()">{{item.title}}</h5>
    <p>{{item.content}}</p>
  </div>      
</div>
```

When the `<h5>` is clicked I want `div.dialog-content` to be displayed in a dialog styled using bootstrap's modal (without modal-header and modal-footer). The dialog closes whenever a user clicks outside of it.

How do I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is... how do I achieve what I described above? I will edit now to reflect that.

Comment: You must move the h5 outside of the div.dialog-content.

Comment: You can select the item inside the repeat and display it in a dialog?

Comment: some clarification, do you want to achieve this with or without ng-dialog?

Comment: @eenagy I am open to any solution. currently, I am tending towards ng-dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this with `ng-dialog`, do the following:

Include `ngDialog.css` and `ngDialog-theme-default.css` in your html.

You have to specify `closeByDocument:true` and add `className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'`

Here is a template :

```
ngDialog.open({ 
     template: '<div> hello dialog!</div>',
     plain:true,
     closeByDocument:true,
     className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
   });
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/kuzidopemo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am getting "TypeError: options.scope.$new is not a function" in the console. Also, how do I set the 'template' option from inside ng-repeat?

Comment: @nubianrover put your code into jsfiddle, or jsbin, or share a git repo, can't help otherwise